# Heatmap with Leaflet and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, leaflet, heatmap

I'm using the angular-leaflet-directive (https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) in one of my apps. I want to create a heatmap layer, but there is no info in the web about how to make this happen. How I can create a heatmap layer with the angular-leaflet-directive?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  A good question will show what you have tried so we can help you solve your existing code.  Stackoverflow is not a resource for finding tools, or having people write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good demo of using the webgl version in the directive's github page.
Here's the link:
http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/heatmap-example.html